# JSON data and Laravel view

Tags: json, laravel, view

I've some JSON data stored in a field of my DB, to display the data in a view, I wrote this query in my controller

```php
$gallerie = Articolo::select('nome_gal')
                    ->where('nome_gal','LIKE','%nome_gal%')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->take(6)
                    ->get();
```

In the controller, I pass that query, and other queries, to a view in this way

```
return view('articoli')->with(array('articoli' => $articoli, 'gallerie'=>$gallerie, 'categorie'=> $categorie, 'trevideo'=>$trevideo, 'treaudio'=>$treaudio));
```

in the sidebar section of the view I used this code:

```html
<div class="sidebar-item popular">
    <h3>Ultime foto</h3>
    <ul class="gallery">
        @foreach(json_decode($gallerie, true) as $galleria)
            <li>{{ $galleria['cover_gal'] }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Well, as a result, when I try to load the page, I don't see any code under the `<ul class="gallery">`.

The structure of the JSON data is this http://p4c.it/alfa.json

Considering that `json_decode` needs a string, in my opinion there is something wrong in the controller part. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried like this <li>{{ $galleria->cover_gal }}</li>

Comment: cover_gal is part of the JSON data. The structure of the JSON data is this http://p4c.it/alfa.json

Comment: First check the query output, I think your query is wrong, in the 'like' clause you have specified the column name(%nome_gal%),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is what i did and it worked for me, in the following, everything is recap, so the solution is complete for the new readers. In the model of the table I defined an imaginary attribute like so:

`protected $appends=['att1','att2','att3', 'att4', 'nome_galla'];`

and obviously

`public function getNomeGallaAttribute()  {
    $json = $this -> attributes['nome_gal'];
    return json_decode($json, true);
}`

in the controller I've the query:

`$gallerie = Articolo::select('nome_gal')->where('nome_gal','LIKE','%nome_gal%')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->take(6)->get();`

and obviously the passage to the view:

`return view('articoli')->with(array('articoli' => $articoli, 'gallerie'=>$gallerie, 'categorie'=> $categorie, 'trevideo'=>$trevideo, 'treaudio'=>$treaudio));`

finally, in the view, I solved in this way:

`<div class="sidebar-item popular">
            <h3>Ultime foto</h3>
            <ul class="gallery">
              @foreach($gallerie as $galleria)
              <li><a href="#"><img src="gallerie/{{$galleria['nome_galla']['nome_della_gal'] }}/img_rid/{{$galleria['nome_galla']['cover_gal'] }}" alt=""></a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>`

for some reason the regular syntax

`{{asset("gallerie/$galleria['nome_galla']['nome_della_gal']/img_rid/$galleria['nome_galla']['cover_gal']")}}`

didn't worked for me (white page of death as a result).

Thanks to everyone for the contribution, I know php but I'm new to laravel :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your JSON data has certain issue:
If you considering  'id_foto' & 'nome_foto'  a pair then it's should be

```
"galleria":[
            {"id_foto": "1","nome_foto": "DSC_0006.JPG"}, 
            {"id_foto": "2","nome_foto": "DSC_0017.JPG"}
           ]
```

instead of

```
"galleria":[{
             "id_foto": "1",
             "nome_foto": "DSC_0006.JPG",
             "id_foto": "2",
             "nome_foto": "DSC_0017.JPG",
             "id_foto": "3"
            }]
```

because when we `json_decode()` your json data we get only the last 'id_foto' & 'nome_foto' like

```
 [galleria] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_foto] => 24 [nome_foto] =>    foto_9.jpg ))
```

which I guess is wrong and check out the edited View code

**Controller**

```
return view('articoli')->with(array('articoli' => $articoli,
'gallerie'=>json_decode($gallerie,true), 'categorie'=> $categorie, 
'trevideo'=>$trevideo, 'treaudio'=>$treaudio));
```

**View [EDITED]**

```
<div class="sidebar-item popular">
    <h3>Ultime foto</h3>
    <ul class="gallery">
         @foreach($gallerie['galleria'] as $galleria=>$gal)
            <li>{{{$gal['id_foto']}}} <br> {{{$gal['nome_foto']}}}</li>
         @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

And to access the keys `nome_gal` & `cover_gal`

```
$gallerie['nome_gal']
$gallerie['cover_gal']
```

Comment: the entire page is white :( I suspected that the JSON data wasn't valid, but, when I try to load it in a test route everything works fine `$gallerie = \App\Articolo::select('nome_gal', 'id_articolo')->where('nome_gal','LIKE','%nome_gal%')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->take(34)->get();

foreach ($gallerie as $galleria) {
  $galla=json_decode($galleria['nome_gal'], true);
  echo '<p>'.$galleria->id_articolo.' - '.$galla['cover_gal'].' - '.$galla['nome_gal'].'</p>';
}`

Comment: looks like your json data has certain issue specially in galleria.

Answer (score 0):

Your json has same key name inside galleria array so it will take the  last value only. instead you can use as

```
{
    "nome_gal": "just a name",
    "cover_gal": "DSC_0017.JPG",
    "galleria": [{
        "id_foto1": 1,
        "nome_foto1": "DSC_0006.JPG",
        "id_foto2": 2,
        "nome_foto2": "DSC_0017.JPG",
        "id_foto3": 3,
        "nome_foto3": "DSC_0018.JPG"
    }]
}
```

Here is your json decoded array

```
Array
(
    [nome_gal] => just a name
    [cover_gal] => DSC_0017.JPG
    [galleria] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_foto] => 24
                    [nome_foto] => foto_9.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: infact it was one of the problems that I've corrected http://p4c.it/gamma.json . Anyway, I'm trying to access cover_gal not galleria. I also tried to simplify my json eliminating the array part but without success. In this moment I'm looking for a working example of json passed to a view